# need to input numbers and output as stars c++

Tags: visual-c++

this is my first question, i have to write a simple program that asks the user to input an integer, where according to the input, it outputs stars according to the input.

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=0;
    char star='*';
    cout<<"Enter number Desired "<<endl;
    cin>> n;

    star=n;
    cout<<' \n'<<star<<endl;
    cout<<' \n'<<star-1<<endl;
    cout<<' \n'<<star-2<<endl;
    cout<<' \n'<<star-3<<endl;
    cout<<' \n'<<star-4<<endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you assign the value of `n` to `star`, then you are overwriting the `*` character which is stored there. Then you are writing out the character value of `n` which is now stored in `star`. What are you expecting the output to be for different numbers? If they are entering from `1` to `5`, then the output will be blank, because they are unprintable ascii control characters

Comment: Your explanation of what the program has to do is unclear. Include a sample output of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: it's like when entering let's say number 5, it should output ***** on the first line, then **** on the below line then *** on the below line then ** on the below line then * on the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print out a descending number of stars from the entered number:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n=0;
    char star='*';
    cout<<"Enter number Desired "<<endl;
    cin>> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) 
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << " " << endl;
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. The plz give me teh codez answer. Too bad it comes without an explanation that a beginner who asks this question might need. And encourages the same bad practices exhibited in the question, like `using namespace std` and `system("pause")`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i edited the code and it appeared to be fine just as i wanted it to be ..

Comment: Ah, yes, the passive aggressive comment. Wouldn't it have been nicer just to make those suggestions without the attitude @CodyGray-onstrike ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a for-loop for printing out stars one by one.
An example is given below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   cout << "*" << endl;
}
```

To make this loop print out less and less stars in each row, use nested for-loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
        cout << "*" << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;
}
```

This loop will print out `n` star characters in the first row, `n-1` characters in the second row, and so on.
Let's say, if `n == 5`, then the output will be:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: it's true that i need a for-loop, but how to do it? i'm taking this at the university and it's like something from outer space and i can't understand it .. :(

Comment: Uh, he's already shown you how to do it @iAbdO. `n` is the number of stars you want to display. It isn't that hard. If you're having trouble following along in class, get a book that teaches C++ programming and catch up.

Comment: @CodyGray This will give the wrong result. The desired output is a number of stars in descending order, as he mentioned in a comment in the question.

Comment: @mike I see. No, I didn't read all of the comments. Too bad that information wasn't in the question so people will actually see it.

Comment: Edited to match the asker's question.